# In ruby, How do I invoke a procedure when defining global variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when checking out the ruby source code,
the accessing of some global variables can be virtual.

I mean
`define_global_variables_get("$a",some_get_procedure)`,
`define_global_variables_set("$a",some_set_procedure)`,
things like that, if I remember correctly,
so actually there is some global variables accessed this way
among that huge set of ruby global variables.

So my question is, how do I define my global variable get/set
like that in ruby code?

Comment: Please rephrase your question because it is confusing. It is really hard to tell what you want to know.

Comment: @user195957, I did find a way to do what (I think) you want.  I've entirely rewritten my answer.  Did I understand what it is you want to do?

Comment: Hello, it's kind of getting part of my story,what I means is getting/setting the global var is just like accessing some procedure,(just like in an object's attribute),class Base;attr_accessor :vow;end, then Base.new.vow is actually a method.

Answer (score 2):

You want a global variable which, when accessed, evaluates your code to get the value of the variable?  You can do that.  You'll want the [promise](http://promise.rubyforge.org/) gem.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'promise'

$a = promise do
  puts "generating value of $a"
  123
end
```

This sets $a to the result of the block, but the block won't be executed until $a is actually accessed.  Let's access it for the first time:

```
puts $a

# => generating value of $a
# => 123
```

Accessing it a second time will return the cached value, so the block will not be called again:

```
puts $a

# => 123
```